# Multi-level (nested) tagging in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, swagger-2.0

I just started working on Swagger 2.0 API recently. I am looking for some ways to organize the API documentation.

Currently I'm using the `@Api(tags = {"Heading1"})` Java annotation to tag each API. The generated documentation looks like

```
Tasks
--------->Heading1
          -------->Desc1
          --------->Desc2
---------->Heading2
          --------->Desc3
          --------->Desc4
```

I'd like to add some subheadings in the doc, so that it looks like

```
Tasks
--------->Heading1
          -------->Desc1
          --------->SubHeading1
                        --------->Desc2
---------->Heading2
          --------->SubHeading1
                     --------->Desc3 
          --------->SubHeading1
                     --------->Desc4
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 21):

Nested tags are not supported by the OpenAPI Specification. Here's the corresponding feature request:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1367

You can try to emulate nested tags by naming your tags `tag1/tag2`, `tag1.tag2`, `tag1|tag2` or similar, but then you'd also have to modify your tools to handle such names as nested tags.

Note for Swagger UI users: There's a feature request to support nested tags using tag names in the form `tag1|tag2` or similar:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5969

Answer (score 1):

As Helen's answer correctly points out, this is not currently possible in Swagger nor vanilla OpenAPI.

However, Swagger alternative [Redoc](https://github.com/Redocly/redoc) introduces and implements an OpenAPI extension called [**`x-tagGroups`**](https://redocly.com/docs/api-reference-docs/specification-extensions/x-tag-groups/) that, as the name suggests, allows you to group tags together under a common heading. This lets you introduce *one* additional nesting level above tags, but no more.

A word of warning though: As of 2024, Redoc lacks a lot of Swagger's features, such as the "Try it out" functionality or being able to show request and response model names. Moreover, Redoc constitutes the open core of a paid offering (Redocly) which *does* implement some of these features, making it unlikely that these will ever make their way into Redoc because it would conflict with their business model. Hence, it's not a drop-in replacement for Swagger.

Answer (score 0):

The creator of the [issue linked in Helen's answer](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5969) has created a plugin for this called [**`swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags). I'll just cite the example Swagger UI HTML file from [its README](https://github.com/kael-shipman/swagger-ui-plugins/blob/combined/packages/hierarchical-tags/README.md):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load Swagger UI -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script> 

    <!-- Load the HierarchicalTags Plugin -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags"></script>

    <!-- Load styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist/swagger-ui.css" />

    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        SwaggerUIBundle({
          url: "https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-plugin-hierarchical-tags/example/pet-store.json",
          dom_id: "#swagger",
          plugins: [
            HierarchicalTagsPlugin
          ],
          hierarchicalTagSeparator: /[:|]/
        })
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="swagger"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Having set up your Swagger UI in this way, you can create tag hierarchies by using `hierarchicalTagSeparator`s in your tag names, e.g. a tag named `MyTopic: MySubtopic: MyTag` will be a tag named `MyTag` in a group named `MySubtopic`, which is in turn grouped under `MyTopic`.