# How to group headers in Swagger UI?

Tags: python, rest, swagger

[using Python, Flask and Swagger UI]

I know you can group method calls in Swagger UI, but can you group the headers that make the calls together? This is so I can make multiple sections on a Swagger UI page.

[Want to group `teams` and `users` together so `teams` becomes a sub-section to `game_players`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rLup.png)

Comment: Do you mean nested headers? [Swagger UI Multi level tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41800330/113116)