# Creating a nested structure of controllers, methods and tags in OpenAPI specification using Swashbuckle

Tags: asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

The issue is, that I have a ASP.Net Core Web API application, which uses SwaggerGen from Swashbuckle to generate OpenAPI specification. There are controllers, such as EmployeesController and ProductsController. There are methods inside each of it, like get/edit/del/etc. How can I make those controllers displayed in the SwaggerUI under the tag Entities, that it will have such a hierarchy - Entities->[EmployeesController, ProductsController, ...]->[get, edit, del, ...]?

I have tried using SwaggerTag and SwaggerOperation attributes with Tag property, but the only result I reached is placing all the methods under the Entities tag, but all the methods were displayed in a list under the Entities, without controllers.

Comment: OpenAPI Specification and Swagger UI [do not support nested tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41800330/113116).

Answer (score 0):

I decided to reorganize the documentation structure so that it doesn't need nesting tags.

> OpenAPI Specification and Swagger UI [do not support nested tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41800330/113116). –
> [Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35220094)